# To Particle or Not to Particle: 今朝は or 今朝

Tags: grammar, particles

If I'm trying to write: 今朝自転車で仕事へ行きました。

Should I write it as above, or should it be 今朝は、自転車で仕事へ行きました。

Is there a general guide for this? Should I prefer it one way or the other when speaking versus when writing?

Comment: Nevermind, guys: some more digging around the internet netted [this previous answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34537/using-particles-with-a-time-as-a-topic/34538#34538)

Comment: I agree with the comment to the linked question.